# String Split VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, split

I have this function:
(server is a textbox field) &
(domain is a textbox field)

```
Function foo As Boolean

    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("site") = "server1.example.com"

If(server.Text.ToLower.Contains((System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("site").ToString.Substring("."))
 OR
domain.Text.ToLower.Contains((System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("site").ToString.Substring(".")))

        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If 
End Function
```

I understand that this will not work because my string split returns a string array, which cannot be compared to the string "server.text".  But how could I re-write this comparison so that I can tell if either the textbox Strings contain the session variable? Keeping in mind I don't want to use any type of iteration over an array of string values.

Expected output:

> server.Text = server1
>   domain.Text = domain2
>   System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("site") = "server1.example.com"
>
> foo = True // server1 = server1

Comment: You can try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735190/parsing-string-for-domain-hostname

Comment: So what if I wasn't using a URI resource and still wanted to preform a similar string... maybe if the string was instead usernames formated first.last name?

Comment: Why not write your own method that does the looping through the split string and returns the string your looking for?

Comment: ***Turn ON OPTION STRICT***

Comment: Why do you need to split the string at all?  Why not just look for the text in the text box and treat the environment variable as a string?

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer in how to take selective parts of a string.split...

ToString.Split(".")(0)     ' takes string in array position 0

ToString.Split(".")(1)     ' takes string in array position 1

ToString.Split(".")(2)     ' takes string in array position 2

so

```
server.Text.ToLower.Contains((System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("site").ToString.Substring("."c)(0))
```

returns true if the first array element is contained in the server string

Comment: Just to note here - you'll get a massive performance overhead if you refer to each of these in turn. You'd be far better assigning the output of `String.Split` to an array: `Dim mySess() As String = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("site").ToString.Split("."C)`

Answer (score 0):

`SubString` won't help you here.

If you want to check whether each URI part is contained in what is in the corresponding textbox, you do it like this:

```
Function foo() As Boolean
    'System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("site") = "server1.domain.com"
    Dim parts() As String = Split(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("site").ToLower, ".")
    If server.Text.ToLower.Contains(parts(0)) OrElse domain.Text.ToLower.Contains(parts(1)) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

If you want the parts to match exactly with either of the corresponding textboxes then you check for equality instead of `Contains`:

```
Function foo() As Boolean
    'System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("site") = "server1.domain.com"
    Dim parts() As String = Split(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("site").ToLower, ".")
    If server.Text.ToLower = parts(0) OrElse domain.Text.ToLower = parts(1) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```