# Need to go from hostname to base domain

Tags: t-sql, powershell, fqdn

I need a function:

```
f(fqdn,suffix) -> basedomain
```

with these example inputs and outputs:

```
f('foobar.quux.somedomain.com','com') -> 'somedomain.com'
f('somedomain.com','com') -> 'somedomain.com'
f('foobar.quux.somedomain.com.br','com.br') -> 'somedomain.com.br'
f('somedomain.com.br','com.br') -> 'somedomain.com.br'
```

In plain English, if the `suffix` has `n` segments, take the last `n+1` segments. Find the base domain for the FQDN, allowing for the fact that some FQDNs have more than one suffix element.

The suffixes I need to match are [here](https://publicsuffix.org/). I've already got them in my SQL database.

I could write this in C#; it might not be the most elegant but it would work. Unfortunately I would like to have this function in either T-SQL, where it is closest to the data, or in Powershell, which is where the rest of the utility that consumes this data is going to be. I suppose it would be ok to do it in C#, compile to an assembly and then access it from T-SQL, or even from Powershell ... if that would be the fastest executing. If there's some reasonably clever alternative in pure T-SQL or simple Powershell, I'd like that.

EDIT: One thing I forgot to mention explicitly (but which is clear when reviewing the suffix list, at my link above) is that we must pick the *longest* matching suffix. Both "br" and "com.br" appear in the suffix list (with similar things happening for uk, pt, etc). So the SQL has to use a window function to make sure the longest matching suffix is found.

Here is how far I got when I was doing the SQL. I had gotten lost in all the `substring`/`reverse` functions.

```
SELECT Domain, suffix
FROM (
    SELECT SD.Domain, SL.suffix, 
       RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY sd.Domain ORDER BY LEN(SL.suffix) DESC)
    FROM SiteDomains SD
    INNER JOIN suffixlist SL ON SD.Domain LIKE '%.'+SL.suffix
) AS X
WHERE RN=1
```

This works ok for finding the right suffix. I'm a little concerned about its performance though.

Comment: I assume you would be using .NET string manipulation in C# to accomplish the task right?  if so you can just do the exact same things in powershell (the string handling is the same and all the methods available in C# are also available in Powershell)

Comment: `$fqdn -replace ".*?(?=[^.]+\.$suffix)"`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler **wow**. That's a mighty brief regex solution. Unfortunately it is not proof against something like  foo.bar.com.br.something.com.br  or even something like my.computers.com

Comment: Instead of relying on regex and string manipulation I think there are better methods for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735190/parsing-string-for-domain-hostname This should translate to PowerShell easily as well with `[system.uri]`

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211973/get-host-domain-from-url

Comment: Darn, I should have anchored it more; `$fqdn -replace "^.*?(?=[^.]+\.$suffix\`$)"` is proof against foo.bar.com.br.something.com.br ...

Comment: @Matt: The accepted answer on the question you linked does NOT do anything whatsoever to get the base domain.

Comment: @RossPresser My mistake I thought the URI class would help with the parsing. I figured there had to be something more than string parsing for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following demonstrates matching FQDNs with TLDs and extracting the desired *n + 1* domain name segments:

```
-- Sample data.
declare @SampleTLDs as Table ( TLD VarChar(64) );
insert into @SampleTLDs ( TLD ) values
  ( 'com' ), ( 'somedomain.com' ), ( 'com.br' );
declare @SampleFQDNs as Table ( FQDN VarChar(64) );
insert into @SampleFQDNs ( FQDN ) values
  ( 'foobar.quux.somedomain.com' ), ( 'somedomain.com' ),
  ( 'foobar.quux.somedomain.com.br' ), ( 'somedomain.com.br' );
select * from @SampleTLDs;
select * from @SampleFQDNs;

-- Fiddle about.
select FQDN, TLD,
  case
    when DotPosition = 0 then FQDN
    else Reverse( Left( ReversedPrefix, DotPosition - 1) ) + '.' + TLD
    end as Result
  from (
    select FQDNs.FQDN, TLDs.TLD,
      Substring( Reverse( FQDNs.FQDN ), Len( TLDs.TLD ) + 2, 100 ) as ReversedPrefix,
      CharIndex( '.', Substring( Reverse( FQDNs.FQDN ), Len( TLDs.TLD ) + 2, 100 ) ) as DotPosition
      from @SampleFQDNs as FQDNs inner join
        @SampleTLDs as TLDs on FQDNs.FQDN like '%.' + TLDs.TLD or FQDNs.FQDN = TLDs.TLD  ) as Edna;

-- To select only the longest matching TLD for each FQDN:
with
  ExtendedFQDNs as (
    select FQDNs.FQDN, TLDs.TLD, Row_Number() over ( partition by FQDN order by Len( TLDs.TLD ) desc ) as TLDLenRank,
      Substring( Reverse( FQDNs.FQDN ), Len( TLDs.TLD ) + 2, 100 ) as ReversedPrefix,
      CharIndex( '.', Substring( Reverse( FQDNs.FQDN ), Len( TLDs.TLD ) + 2, 100 ) ) as DotPosition
      from @SampleFQDNs as FQDNs inner join
        @SampleTLDs as TLDs on FQDNs.FQDN like '%.' + TLDs.TLD or FQDNs.FQDN = TLDs.TLD )
  select FQDN, TLD,
    case
      when DotPosition = 0 then FQDN
      else Reverse( Left( ReversedPrefix, DotPosition - 1) ) + '.' + TLD
      end as Result
    from ExtendedFQDNs
    where TLDLenRank = 1;
```

Comment: This is good, but needs a refinement that I didn't mention explicitly in the question (but it is implicit if you look at the suffix list link). Both "br" and "com.br" appear in the suffix list; the longest suffix must be preferred. I'll add this to my question.

Comment: This works extremely well when paired with the [left self join](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8749095/864696) technique for finding the longest matching suffix. If you update your answer for that I'll accept it.

Comment: @RossPresser The answer has been updated: (1) corrected the sample date, (b) corrected handling of FQDN = TLD case, (iii) added example that picks the "best", i.e. longest TLD, match for each FQDN.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it in C#:

```
string getBaseDomain(string fqdn, string suffix)
{
    string[] domainSegs = fqdn.Split('.');
    return domainSegs[domainSegs.Length - suffix.Split('.').Length - 1] + "." + suffix;
}
```

So here it is in Powershell:

```
function getBaseDomain
{
  Param(
    [string]$fqdn, 
    [string]$suffix 
  )
  $domainSegs = $fqdn.Split(".");
  return $domainSegs[$domainSegs.Length - $suffix.Split(".").Length - 1] + "."+$suffix;
}
```

Seems rather silly now to have wasted stackoverflow.com's time with this. My apologies.

Comment: Take a look at the answers and comments, you don't need to apologize for this : )

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tsql variant...

```
declare @fqdn varchar(256) = 'somedomain.com'
declare @suffix varchar(128) = 'com'

select left(@fqdn,CHARINDEX(@suffix,@fqdn) - 2)

if(select CHARINDEX('.',reverse(left(@fqdn,CHARINDEX(@suffix,@fqdn) - 2)))) = 0
    begin
    select left(@fqdn,CHARINDEX(@suffix,@fqdn) - 2) + '.' + @suffix
    end
else
    begin
    select right(left(@fqdn,CHARINDEX(@suffix,@fqdn) - 2),CHARINDEX('.',reverse(left(@fqdn,CHARINDEX(@suffix,@fqdn) - 2))) - 1) + '.' + @suffix
    end
```